# A simple but curious determinantal inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, matrix-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ Hermitian positive definite matrices and $k>0$ real. Then $A^k$ is well-defined and experimentally, we have $$\det(A^k+BABA^{-1})\geqslant \det(A^k+BA^{-1}BA),$$or equivalently $$\det(A^k+A^{-1}BAB)\geqslant \det(A^k+ABA^{-1}B).$$ Note that this would imply the inequality $\color{green}{\det (A^2+BAAB)\geqslant \det(A^2+ABBA)}$ found (but presumably unproved) by M. Lin, which is mentioned [in a comment here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224121/which-ordering-of-factors-is-needed-to-obtain-this-kind-of-determinantal-inequal#comment553367_224121).

One striking fact is that $B$ (or $A$, same outcome) can be multiplied by a positive factor, which means that the inequality remains valid for any  "proportionality" between the two terms of each sum. Indeed, for any $\lambda>0$, we have equivalently $$\det(A^k+\color{red}\lambda BABA^{-1})\geqslant \det(A^k+\color{red}\lambda BA^{-1}BA).$$

> Any ideas how to prove this conjecture?

Comment: I have some other generalizations based on your very interesting determinantal conjectures --- I wish I had time to think about these. Do you have numerical evidence for these? The second one suggests that perhaps there is even a Löwner dominance somewhere that yields the ineq for all $\lambda\ge 0$.

Comment: @Suvrit Yes I wouldn't have posted that without checking first for several thousands of random matrices of different sizes and several big and small values of $k$. I almost thought my few lines of PARI code had a bug... :-)

Comment: have you tried Tao's strategy: proving that the spectrum of $C=A^{-(k+1)/2}BABA^{-(k+1)/2}$ is majorated by the spectrum of $D=A^{-(k-1)/2}BA^{-1}BA^{-(k-1)/2}$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov That looks like an appealing idea, but I already have a hard time following how he re-arranges the traces. And no idea how to use that method with inverses, let alone arbitrary powers, even the k=2 case.

Comment: Just noted that it can be written more symmetrically as follows: Putting $C:=A^{-1}BA$ and $D:=ABA^{-1}$, then $\boxed{\det(A^k+CD)\geqslant \det(A^k+DC)}$.

Comment: The multiplication by $\lambda$ is a red-herring, because you could trivially replace $B$ by $\sqrt{\lambda}B$ without changing anything, so we might as well prove the $\lambda=1$ case.

Comment: @Suvrit of course, I know. But I found it funny to notice that this means the two terms of the sum can have any difference of "magnitude". :)

Comment: Sorry to have confused you, I had known this $\det (A^2+BAAB)\geqslant \det(A^2+ABBA)$. It follows from COROLLARY 2.3 of the paper M. Lin,  H. Wolkowicz, An eigenvalue majorization inequality for positive semidefinite block matrices, Linear Multilinear Algebra 60 (2012), no. 11-12, 1365–1368. http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03081087.2011.651723

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C = A^{-(k+1)/2} B A B A^{-(k+1)/2}$ and $D = A^{-(k-1)/2} B A^{-1} B A^{-(k-1)/2}$ .

We have to show that $det(I+C) \ge det(I+D)$ .

Now my goal is to apply equation (5.21) in Ando, Majorizations and Inequalities in Matrix Theory, http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379594903417/1-s2.0-0024379594903417-main.pdf?_tid=1af72ca2-58c4-11e7-a518-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1498298674_bf9275307496eb46505ba4b5b84a7dcc :

Choose $E = A^{-(k+1)/2} B A^{-(k+1)/2}$ and $F = A^{k/2+1}$.

Then $C^{1/2} = \vert F E \vert$ and $D^{1/2} = \vert F^{a_1} E^{b_1} F^{a_2} E^{b_2} \vert$ ,
where $a_1 = (k/2)/(k/2+1)$, $b_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 1/(k/2+1)$, $b_2 = 0$.

Since $0 \le a_1 \le b_1$ and $0 \le a_2$  and $0 \le b_2$ and $a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2 = 1$ it follows that $D^{1/2} \prec_{\log} C^{1/2}$ and therefore $D \prec_{\log} C$.

Since $log(1+e^x)$ is convex in $x$ it follows that $I+C$ weakly log majorizes $I+D$ and therefore $det(I+C) \ge det(I+D)$ .

Comment: Shouldn't it be (k+1)/2 in the definition of E?

Comment: @Wolfgang : Yes, corrected.

Comment: @jjcale, would you try Conjecture 4.2 in the paper http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219199716500449

Comment: @M.Lin, can you state the conjecture here, please?

Comment: Here is the link to the arXiv preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04141v1.pdf

Comment: @M.Lin Thank you! So for Hermitian p.d. matrices $A,B$ and $0\leqslant q\leqslant 1$, this can be stated simply as $\det (A^2+(BAAB)^q)\geqslant \det(A^2+A^{2q}B^{2q})$ or (to get rid of the '$A^2$'), as $\boxed{\color{green}{\det (A+(BAB)^q)\geqslant \det(A+A^{q}B^{2q})}}$.

Comment: @Wolfgang, Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 4):

*EDIT (added some clarifications)*. The argument below provides a self-contained proof.

Introduce the shorthand $C^{-2}=A^{k+1}$. We need to show that
\begin{equation*}
  \det(I+ CBABC) \ge \det(I + CABA^{-1}BAC).
\end{equation*}

We will prove this inequality by establishing the log-majorization
\begin{equation*}
  \prod\nolimits_{j=1}^k\lambda_j(CABA^{-1}BAC) 
  \le
  \prod\nolimits_{j=1}^k\lambda_j(CBABC),\quad 1\le j \le n.
\end{equation*}
This log-majorization is equivalent to $\lambda_1(\wedge^k (CABA^{-1}BAC)) \le \lambda_1(\wedge^k(CBABC))$ (for $1\le k\le n$). It suffices to show this for $k=1$; the general case follows similarly upon exploiting the multiplicativity of the wedge product.

Thus, to prove $\lambda_1(CABA^{-1}BAC) \le \lambda_1(CBABC)$, we use its *scale independence* and observe that for positive matrices $X$ and $Y$, we have
\begin{equation*}
[Y \le I \implies X \le I] \implies \lambda_1(X)\le \lambda_1(Y).
\end{equation*}

Thus, to prove the $\lambda_1$ inequality, it suffices to prove that
\begin{equation*}
  CBABC \le I \Leftrightarrow\ 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A^{k+1} & B\\
    B & A^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix} \ge 0\quad\implies  CABA^{-1}BAC \le I.
\end{equation*}
But $\begin{bmatrix}
    A^{k+1} & B\\
    B & A^{-1}
  \end{bmatrix} \ge 0$ only if $B\le \sqrt{A^{k+1}A^{-1}}=A^{k/2}$; and if this is so, then it must also be the case that $\begin{bmatrix}
    A^{k-1} & B\\
    B      & A
  \end{bmatrix} \ge 0$. Notice now that $A^{k-1} = C^{-2}A^{-2}$, and apply  Schur complements to the latter matrix inequality to obtain
\begin{equation*}
  BA^{-1}B \le C^{-2}A^{-2}\Leftrightarrow CABA^{-1}BAC \le I.
\end{equation*}
Thus, we have shown that $\lambda_1(CABA^{-1}BAC) \le \lambda_1(CBABC)$. In a similar manner we can prove the general case for $k>1$, which ends up establishing the desired log-majorization.

This finishes the proof of the claim because $\lambda(X) \prec_{\log} \lambda(Y) \implies \det(I+X) \le \det(I+Y)$.

Comment: How can you see that $B \le A^{k/2}$ ? $B$ is positive definite but otherwise arbitrary .

Comment: Yes, how can you apply your first lemma if $Y\le I$ doesn't hold?

Comment: @jjcale Because it's a conditional statement; if we have $CBABC\le I$, then we have $B\le A^{k/2}$. What we really wanted to prove was the eigenvalue domination; we reduced that to showing that $Y\le I \implies X \le I$ must hold (note that $\lambda(\cdot)$ is positively homogeneous).

Comment: Actually, I should be a bit more precise, and just write that what I am using is the observation:
$(0 \le Y \le I \implies 0 \le X \le I) \implies \lambda_1(X)\le \lambda_1(Y)$

Comment: So you mean your proof only works if CBABC≤I? Well, granted, but then that's a very special case only.

Comment: No, I mean, the proof works in general; just the proof technique looks a bit confusing (because it is a chained implication). When I find some time, I can try to expand / edit my explanation above to make it clearer!